# Enable networking without the gnome-applet

Tags: 10.04, gnome, networking, command-line, xmonad

I've switched to XMonad as my window manager. Sometimes when I put my laptop to hibernate, it's hanging and won't shut down. I have to force it off by pressing the powerbutton for 5 seconds.

After I boot again, I can't connect to the internet. I have to logout, go to gnome, and after logging in, I rightclick the network applet icon and select the enable networking options. After that, my internet is working again.

Is there a way to do this via the command line or another option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise xmonad with status bar and tray apps for utilities like network-manager which need tray icons.

[This guide](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/John_Goerzen%27s_Configuration), for example, details how to set up xmobar and trayer, among other things.

Comment: It seems a good sollution. The only problem is that I can't seem to get trayer on the top of my screen. It just doesn't appear.

Comment: Temporarily fixed the problem by adjusting my xorg.conf to allow for only one screen. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/10005/getting-trayer-to-work-with-dual-screen-setup

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nmcli` (part of NM) or `cnetworkmanager`

```
sudo apt-get install cnetworkmanager
```

to control NetworkManager from the commandline.

BTW: you can configure Monad to use a panel or such (but maybe that's not what you want).

Comment: basically this, disable: `nmcli nm enable false` enable: `nmcli nm enable true`, no sudo required! saw [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969533&p=11900910#post11900910)

Answer (score 1):

I find after improper shutdowns that the /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf often has Managed=False set.  When you go into GNOME and hit that checkbox, all you're doing is toggling that to True.  You can do it with a text editor too.

Comment: Setting it to true doesn't solve the issue, and it seems enableing networking doesn't set it to true

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you've killed the network-manager daemon. You can restart it by doing `sudo service network-manager start`. However if you're not using network-manager you can always remove it all together (and probably eliminate this issue).

Comment: The network manager is still running (NetworkManager process). And I use nm-applet to get wireless connection.