# Getting trayer to work with dual screen setup

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm using XMonad as my window manager, and want to use trayer as a icon panel for things like nm-applet.

The problem was that the panel wouldn't appear on the top of the screen. If I set it to the bottom it just appeared.

After a lot of trying, I found out it is because my xorg.conf is setup for dualscreens, and probably the trayer panel is spawned outside my view (I currently have only a single screen, but I switch a lot).

After manualy tweaking the xorg.conf file to allow for just one screen, the panel appears on the right spot.

These are the things I had to modify:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-LVDS"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "0 0" # Was 1280 256
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   1366 768 # Was 2646 2646
        Depth     24
EndSubSection
```

The problem is ofcourse that I can't use my dual screen setup anymore. Is there a way to force trayer on the right position even with the dualscreen setup?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you are right when you say "the trayer panel is spawned outside my view". I just posted this answer in another forum (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=878706#p878706)

I think the problem is the interaction between where you place trayer and the virtual screen size and layout.  I had a similar problem where the trayer (bottom right) disappeared with my dual screen set up. In my case, I got into trouble doing this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --primary --rotate normal --pos 0x0 --output VGA1 --rotate normal --left-of LVSD1

trayer --edge bottom --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true --expand true --widthtype request --transparent true --tint 0x191970 --height 12 --distance 20 --distancefrom right
```

(LVSD1 is my laptop)

The problem is that the left monitor is 1280x1024 whereas the laptop is 1600x900. That means that the trayer (--edge bottom) is located below the lower part of the laptop's screen. An easy fix is to align the bottom of the two screens, for instance doing (with my setup)

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --primary --rotate normal --pos 1280x124 --output VGA1 --rotate normal --auto --pos 0x0
```

Maybe in your case its just a matter of specifying the position of your primary monitor AND the trayer edge option so that they play nicely with each other.

P.S.1. I think in most recent distros with recent xorg, you do not really need to specify an xorg.conf file.

Comment: My graphic cards driver automatically generates a xorg.conf. If I enable my second screen with screen expanding, it automatically sets the virtual display size, and I have to reboot for it to take place.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you can take is to use a fork of trayer that has multi-monitor support: https://github.com/sargon/trayer-srg

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using stalonetray right now. This application allows you to absolutely place the traybar, which solves the problem.